# tbl_summary's descriptive statistics table, without the statistics column?

Tags: r, gtsummary

How can one present a summary table like the one produced by the [code below](http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html), but with only one column (Characteristics) i.e. without the second column with statistics "N = 200"?

Am thinking of using tbl_summary to create tables from a model which gives results in a dataframe, thus the dataframe has many columns, but with only 1 row (the stats from that model), and this is what I would like to display nicely.

```
trial2 %>% tbl_summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide any column from the output using the `modify_column_hide()` function.

```r
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  modify_column_hide(columns = all_stat_cols())
```

Comment: does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you